# Как перевести на русский слово "prepster"?

Tags: перевод, сленг

Слово образовано из слияния preppy + hipster. Словарь дает такое определение: "культурный маргинал, сочетающий консервативное и либеральное". Preppy = старомодный, hipster = неформал (примерно). Можно ли как-то адаптировать это понятие на русском одним словом? Например "стиляга"? Или здесь лучше обойтись прямой транслитерацией и сноской в тексте с объяснением значения?

Comment: a можете, пожалуйста, подтвердить своё определение какой-то внешней ссылкой (или указать словарь на который вы опираетесь) - если гуглить в гугле, во-первых, гуглится плохо (то есть термин редкий), во-вторых в Urban Dictionary даётся определение - не совпадающее с вашим: the prepster is someone most likely raised in the suburbs and very preppy, that moves to a very hipster centered city (Brooklyn, Portland, Austin), and due to scene exposure adopts certain hipster trends whilst retaining the preppy spirit. Preppy - это не старомодный.

Comment: @shabunc - А ведь определение в Urban Dictionary не расходится с тем, что даёт ОР. По-вашему, всё дело в том, где провести грань между «старомодный» и «консервативный»? Других различий, похоже, нет.

Comment: @YellowSky  preppy это и не консервативный и не старомодный, вот ей-богу

Comment: "preppy" - это особый тип консервативности и старомодности.

Comment: ""культурный маргинал, сочетающий консервативное и либеральное"  - пипец... ну, как перевести... например - шут гороховый :)

Comment: "Например "стиляга"?" - нет.
Если вам без такой терминологии не обойтись - никак не переводите :) Препстер :>

Answer (score 3):

Начнём с того, что preppy - это не старомодный, это определённый стиль одежды, он действительно имеет истоки в в студенческой американской моде, которой уже лет 70, но с тех пор он постоянно эволюционировал и был в той или иной своей инкарнации актуальным явлением. В восприятии этого стиля есть определённо оттеннок ретро, и это в каком-то смысле это сближает его с нашим понятием стиляги. Но стиляги всё-таки это совсем другое явление - и по природе происхождения, и по визуальному коду и, наконец, опять-таки по степени актуальности.

Например, вот что вам более-менее выдаст гугловый поиск по картинкам по запросу "preppy fashion":

[image]

Теперь что касается prepster - во-первых, совершенно точно это не распространённое слово - например, поиск по картинкам ничего толкового вам не даст. Согласно [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=prepster),

> the prepster is someone most likely raised in the suburbs and very preppy, that moves to a very hipster centered city (Brooklyn, Portland, Austin), and due to scene exposure adopts certain hipster trends whilst retaining the preppy spirit.

Мы можем долго спорить о том, тождественен ли наш хипстер хипстеру портландскому или бруклинскому, одевается ли он похоже, опять-таки, что есть "наш" в данном случае (московский хипстер, одесский, харьковский, минский, питерский?) но мне кажется, что в данном случае речь идёт об очень конкретном явлении, локальном для очень конкретного набора географических мест.

Поэтому я бы не стал переводить prepster никак, точно так же как я не стал бы рекомендовать кому-то переводить на английский термин типа стиляга-любер. Ну, или, если это художественный текст где этот термин упоминается один раз, я бы просто раскрыл этот термин.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, так и сделаю.

Comment: редкий случай - данные картинки ничего не объясняют :>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *культурный маргинал, сочетающий консервативное и либеральное* quite captures the meaning.

"Preppy" means "looking and behaving like a prep school student". It is quite a foreign concept to Russia. Russia has not been historically big on old private prep schools.

The closest thing to "preppy" in Russian seems to be *мажор* or *мальчик-мажор*, although it's quite a stretch. "Preppy" is more specific to polo shirts and argyle jerseys.

Russian language also does not form portmanteaus as readily as English does.

With all that said, I don't think there's a single Russian word that would ring all the same bells the English one does. Looks like you will have to do with a loanword and a footnote explanation.

Comment: а как вы представляете культурного маргинала, сочетающего (в одежде я полагаю) консервативное и либеральное? Я закрываю глаза - но у меня ничего не выходит, кроме Агузаровой - не получается у меня никакого конкретного образа - а с prepster-ом кстати получается (слова не слышал, кто имеется ввиду в плане одежды - понимаю)

Comment: @shabunc: Is that a question to me? I don't

Comment: Спасибо, в таком случае ограничусь транслитерацией.